# Exponent p-value generated in Excel

Tags: real-analysis, statistics, exponentiation, data-analysis, statistical-mechanics

Excel gave me a p-value of 1.44909E-09 
Notice is does not say .09 but 09 
This is confusing me, I am trying to analyze my data but am stuck at this point. 
If it were E-9 it could be 1.44909/1000000000 ? 
 The rest of the data I have looks like this (blood pressure data): The mean SBP for control is 116.525 and experimental 119.125. The mean DBP for control is 67.575 and experimental 80.05. The standard deviation SBP for control is 15.076 and experimental is 20.613. The standard deviation DBP for control is 8.003 and experimental 11.856. 
The p-value for the control data-set is 39%. The p-value for the experimental data-set is ????

(also, since both data sets were close in range, is the data not significant?)

Comment: $1.44909E-09 = 1.44909×10^{-9} = 0.00000000144909$

Comment: wow, thank you! that's quite a difference from the other p-value of 0.391084509 !

Comment: you are welcome! When I see differences like that, I make sure that there was not some data error and I use another tool to validate my data and results. There are some great free tools out there, like [*CAS*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_computer_algebra_systems) and other stat tools, so it might help to check that out and understand your data set. Regards

Comment: How large is your data set?

Comment: 40 college students had their blood pressures taken. control SBP/DBP and experimental SBP/DBP

Comment: You might want to post your data set since it is small and have someone validate your results.

Comment: awesome, thanks for the suggestion, i'll do that as soon as 1) i figure out how to, and 2) i receive the email with the raw data